# How to get Active Directory domain name from windows 10 client

Tags: 18.04, dns, active-directory, openldap

I install OpenLDAP as an Active Directory on ubuntu 18.04 and I connect my windows client by pGina. Its work fine but when ping my server ip address it reply but if I ping my host name nad.nassa.lan then its not working. I also try nslookup nad.nassa.lan
it show
'''server-unknown
address - 192.168.55.93'''

if do this from my server it show
'''server: 127.0.0.53
address: 127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
name: nad.nassa.lan
Address: 192.168.55.93'''

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows Taskbar, click **Start** > **Programs** > **Administrative Tools** > **Active Directory Domains and Trusts**

In the left pane of the Active Directory Domains and Trusts dialog box, look under Active Directory Domains and Trusts.

The FQDN for the computer or computers is listed.

**Note:**  This information should also be located under **System Properties** > **Computer Name** next to Domain, and under Active Directory Users and Computers.

Comment: but I don't have Active Directory Domains and Trusts option.